# How to properly compare an integer and a floating-point value?

Tags: c++, floating-point

How do I compare an integer and a floating-point value *the right way™*?

The builtin comparsion operators give incorrect results in some edge cases, for example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long a = 999999984306749439;
    float     b = 999999984306749440.f; // This number can be represented exactly by a `float`.

    std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);
    std::cout << a << " < " << b << " = " << (a < b) << '\n';
    // Prints `999999984306749439 < 999999984306749440 = 0`, but it should be `1`.
}
```

Apparently, the comparsion operators convert both operands to a same type before actually comparing them. Here lhs gets converted to `float`, which causes a loss of precision, and leads to an incorrect result.

Even though I understand what's going on, I'm not sure how to work around this issue.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: The example uses a `float` and a `long long`, but I'm looking for a generic solution that works for every combination of an integral type and a floating-point type.</sup>

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Define the sort of "comparison" you're after. You cannot solve an unspecified problem.

Comment: Convert the floating point type into the integer type?

Comment: My first idea would be to cast the float to a long long.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica But what if the integer type is not large enough? I'm not even sure how to check if it's large enough.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I'm trying to check if one number is less than the other number, in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To what level of precision? To the level of all significant figures given in the respective initialisers? To something else?

Comment: Okay, convert both to a long double.  Can't really break anything with that although you may lose some precision on the integer but that's to be expected when working with floating point types.

Comment: How are you getting so many usable decimal places from a `float` o.O

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica *"How are you getting so many usable decimal places"* By carefully picking the float. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat lol ok- well that's another important point: will you be carefully picking all your other floats? Is that a prerequisite for your desired algorithm? There are loads of gaps in the requirements here

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Answering the question about precision: Every integer variable and every floating-point variable (unless it's a NaN or infinity) represents a specific number, which is finite and has a finite amount of digits after the decimal point. I want to compare those represented numbers. That means, with full precision (that is, without discarding 'garbage' digits from floats).

Comment: @uneven_mark What do you mean? Do you say I should specify if I used IEEE floats or not, or that I should break down that float to the mantissa & exponent and add it to the question?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: OP picked 999999984306749440 which is an exact IEEE754 32 bit `float`, although the space is sparse in that region. The next one differs from it by the GDP of a small country.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you we did cover that

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: I'll get me coat.

Comment: This works: `float c = a; std::cout << a << " < " << b << " = " << ((a-(long long)c) < (b-c)) << '\n';`  It should be a generic fix to "implicit conversion lost precision".  "One of the values is out of range for the other datatype" is a different problem that needs a different solution.

Comment: @Bathsheba You've pulled? 

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: Not since May 1996. Wouldn't know where to start these days.

Comment: @Bathsheba Gosh good luck

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: Yup I married young!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing uint64_t and float for numeric equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32810583/995714), [Compare a 32 bit float and a 32 bit integer without casting to double, when either value could be too large to fit the other type exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43862716/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Those are interesting, but I don't think mine is a dupe. The first one asks specifically about equality, and the second one only asks about two specific types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with.

Credit for the algorithm goes to @chux; his approach appears to outperform the other suggestions. You can find some alternative implementations in the edit history.

If you can think of any improvements, suggestions are welcome.

```cpp
#include <compare>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename I, typename F>
std::partial_ordering compare_int_float(I i, F f)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<F> && std::is_floating_point_v<I>)
    {
        return 0 <=> compare_int_float(f, i);
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<I> && std::is_floating_point_v<F>);
        static_assert(std::numeric_limits<F>::radix == 2);
        
        // This should be exactly representable as F due to being a power of two.
        constexpr F I_min_as_F = std::numeric_limits<I>::min();
        
        // The `numeric_limits<I>::max()` itself might not be representable as F, so we use this instead.
        constexpr F I_max_as_F_plus_1 = F(std::numeric_limits<I>::max()/2+1) * 2;

        // Check if the constants above overflowed to infinity. Normally this shouldn't happen.
        constexpr bool limits_overflow = I_min_as_F * 2 == I_min_as_F || I_max_as_F_plus_1 * 2 == I_max_as_F_plus_1;
        if constexpr (limits_overflow)
        {
            // Manually check for special floating-point values.
            if (std::isinf(f))
                return f > 0 ? std::partial_ordering::less : std::partial_ordering::greater;
            if (std::isnan(f))
                return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
        }

        if (limits_overflow || f >= I_min_as_F)
        {
            // `f <= I_max_as_F_plus_1 - 1` would be problematic due to rounding, so we use this instead.
            if (limits_overflow || f - I_max_as_F_plus_1 <= -1)
            {
                I f_trunc = f;
                if (f_trunc < i)
                    return std::partial_ordering::greater;
                if (f_trunc > i)
                    return std::partial_ordering::less;
            
                F f_frac = f - f_trunc;
                if (f_frac < 0)
                    return std::partial_ordering::greater;
                if (f_frac > 0)
                    return std::partial_ordering::less;
                    
                return std::partial_ordering::equivalent;
            }

            return std::partial_ordering::less;
        }
        
        if (f < 0)
            return std::partial_ordering::greater;
        
        return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
    }
}
```

If you want to experiment with it, here are a few test cases:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream> 

void compare_print(long long a, float b, int n = 0)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        auto result = compare_int_float(a,b);
        static constexpr std::partial_ordering values[] = {std::partial_ordering::less, std::partial_ordering::equivalent, std::partial_ordering::greater, std::partial_ordering::unordered};
        std::cout << a << ' ' << "<=>?"[std::find(values, values+4, result) - values] << ' ' << b << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b = std::nextafter(b, -INFINITY);
            
        for (int i = 0; i <= n*2; i++)
        {
            compare_print(a, b);
            b = std::nextafter(b, INFINITY);
        }
        
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{    
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);
    
    compare_print(999999984306749440,
                  999999984306749440.f, 2);
                  
    compare_print(999999984306749439,
                  999999984306749440.f, 2);
                  
    compare_print(100,
                  100.f, 2);
    
    compare_print(-100,
                  -100.f, 2);
                  
    compare_print(0,
                  0.f, 2);
                                    
    compare_print((long long)0x8000'0000'0000'0000,
                  (long long)0x8000'0000'0000'0000, 2);
                                    
    compare_print(42, INFINITY);
    compare_print(42, -INFINITY);
    compare_print(42, NAN);
    std::cout << '\n';

    compare_print(1388608,
                  1388608.f, 2);
    
    compare_print(12388608,
                  12388608.f, 2);
}
```

<sup>[(run the code)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d89d5d93c3df1165)</sup>

Comment: Very nice indeed Sir!

Comment: Looks good, but you can suppress the result_if_eq: `(F) i` will never have a fractional part: either F has more precision than I, then (F) i conversion is exact (no fraction part) or I has more bits than F precision, but in this case (F) i cannot have a fraction part either (the ulp is > 1).

Comment: Since you are in the case `(F) i == f`, if `(F) i` does not have a fraction part, neither has `f`

Comment: @aka.nice You're right, I didn't think about that. Edited.

Comment: You can also safely remove the `isinf(f)` test, this is already covered by `(F) i < f` and `(F) i > f` tests, unless the integer type has so many bits that it could overflow max float (unlikely, but you could eventually cover this condition with a static assertion)

Comment: There are other implementation defined optimizations that could be covered by static assertions: assuming two complement, and F radix = 2, then INTEGER_MIN magnitude is a power of two and `(I) (F) INTEGER_MIN` cannot overflow (it is exact). Thus no need to cover float_too_large condition for negative f. BTW, did you test INTEGER_MIN case?

Comment: @aka.nice Regarding the isinf(f) test - good point, I've put it behind a constexpr condition. Regarding INTEGER_MIN - I don't quite get what changes you suggest. I've added it to the test cases in the answer for the convenience. (At first I though you're suggesting removing the `+ (std::is_signed` part, but doing it gives an incorrect result.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean that integer overflow in `(I) f` can only happen when `f == (F) INTEGER_MAX`, not when `f == (F) INTEGER_MIN` under above assumptions, so we need to care only of former case. Beside INTEGER_MIN and INTEGER_MAX generally differ in 1 bit of magnitude, so I'm unsure about current handling...

Comment: @aka.nice Hmm. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ae4afef82474368) are some more test cases. The current solution appears to work on them.

Comment: Ah OK, you harcoded the two-complement assumption via `+ (std::is_signed_v<I> && frac == F(-0.5))`, I see it now. The condition `exp ==...` cannot happen for `numeric_limits<I>::min()` in case of two-complement AND `numeric_limits<I>::radix==numeric_limit<F>::radix`, because `(F) i == f` and `(F) numeric_limits<I>::min()` is then exact. Both implementation defined assumptions are implcit in your code because you compare float max exponent and int digits, which is only possible if sharing same radix...

Comment: I think `(std::numeric_limits<I>::max()/2+1) * 2;` needs review to handle cases where range of `I` exceed `F`.  Consider `int128_t` and `float`.  In my code I cheated and used `*2.0` to use `double` math when `F` is `float`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think I've handled that by adding the `limits_overflow` thing. I've not tested it though.

Answer (score 4):

(Restricting this answer to positive numbers; generalisation is trivial.)

1. Get the number of bits in your exponent for the `float` on your platform along with the radix. If you have an IEEE754 32 bit `float` then this is a trivial step.
2. Use (1) to compute the largest non-integer value that can be stored in your `float`. `std::numeric_limits` doesn't specify this value, annoyingly, so you need to do this yourself. For 32 bit IEEE754 you could take the easy option: `8388607.5` is the largest non-integral type `float`.
3. If your `float` is less than or equal to (2), then check if it's an integer or not. If it's not an integer then you can round it appropriately so as not to invalidate the `<`.
4. At this point, the `float` is an integer. Check if it's within in the range of your `long long`. If it's out of range then the result of `<` is known.
5. If you get this far, then you can safely cast your `float` to a `long long`, and make the comparison.

Comment: Looks promising; I need to think about it for a bit. I guess I'll try to implement your idea in code and will post it as an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Which I'd upvote, ping me when you've done it! Personally I'd collapse the first two steps to the simple `8388607.5` check.

Answer (score 3):

To compare a FP `f` and *integer* `i` for equality:

(Code is representative and uses comparison of `float` and `long long` as an example)

1. If `f` is a NaN, infinity, or has a fractional part  (perhaps use `frexp()`), `f` is not equal to `i`.

   ```
   float ipart;
   // C++
   if (frexp(f, &ipart) != 0) return not_equal;
   // C
   if (frexpf(f, &ipart) != 0) return not_equal;
   ```
2. Convert the numeric limits of `i` into *exactly representable* FP values (powers of 2) near those limits.<sup>**</sup>  Easy to do if we assume FP is not a rare base 10 encoding and range of `double` exceeds the range on the `i`.  Take advantage that integer limits magnitudes are or near [Mersenne Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html).  (Sorry example code is C-ish)

   ```
   #define FP_INT_MAX_PLUS1 ((LLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)
   #define FP_INT_MIN (LLONG_MIN*1.0)
   ```
3. Compare `f` to is limits

   ```
   if (f >= FP_INT_MAX_PLUS1) return not_equal;
   if (f < FP_INT_MIN) return not_equal;
   ```
4. Convert `f` to integer and compare

   ```
   return (long long) f == i;
   ```

---

To compare a FP `f` and *integer* `i` for `<`, `>`, `==` or not comparable:

(Using above limits)

1. Test `f >= lower limit`

   ```
   if (f >= FP_INT_MIN) {
   ```
2. Test `f <= upper limit`

   ```
     // reform below to cope with effects of rounding
     // if (f <= FP_INT_MAX_PLUS1 - 1)
     if (f - FP_INT_MAX_PLUS1 <= -1.0) {
   ```
3. Convert `f` to integer/fraction and compare

   ```
       // at this point `f` is in the range of `i`
       long long ipart = (long long) f;
       if (ipart < i) return f_less_than_i;
       if (ipart > i) return f_more_than_i;

       float frac = f - ipart;
       if (frac < 0) return f_less_than_i;
       if (frac > 0) return f_more_than_i;
       return equal;
     }
   ```
4. Handle edge cases

   ```
     else return f_more_than_i;
   }
   if (f < 0.0) return f_less_than_i;
   return not_comparable;
   ```

Simplifications possible, yet I wanted to convey the algorithm.

---

<sup>**</sup>  Additional conditional code needed to cope with non 2's complement integer encoding.  It is quite similar to the `MAX` code.

Comment: I [benchmarked](http://quick-bench.com/hvx-hKyHKy_B4AKze52XDyft160) it, and your approach seems to be faster than what I used to have in the answer (even after I removed `frexp` from mine). I've C++-ified it a bit and added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The code below works with integer data types of at most 64 bits and 
    floating point data types of at most ieee-754 double precision accuracy.
    For wider data types the same idea can be used, but you'll have to adapt he code.
    Since I'm not very familiar with C++, the code is written in C. It shouldn't be too
    difficult to convert it to a C++ style code. The code is branchless, which might 
    be a performance benefit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// gcc -O3 -march=haswell cmp.c
// Assume long long int is 64 bits.
// Assume ieee-754 double precision.
int long_long_less_than_double(long long int i, double y) {
    long long i_lo = i & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;   // Extract lower 32 bits.
    long long i_hi = i & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;   // Extract upper 32 bits.
    double x_lo = (double)i_lo;                // Exact conversion to double, no rounding errors!
    double x_hi = (double)i_hi;                // 
    return ( x_lo < (y - x_hi) );              // If i is close to y then y - x_hi is exact,
                                               // due to Sterbenz' lemma.
    // i < y
    // i_lo +i_hi < y      
    // i_lo < (y - i_hi)
    // x_lo < (y - x_hi)
}

int long_long_equals_double(long long int i, double y) {
    long long i_lo = i & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;   
    long long i_hi = i & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;   
    double x_lo = (double)i_lo;                    
    double x_hi = (double)i_hi;                    
    return ( x_lo == (y - x_hi) );                  
}                                                  


int main()
{
    long long a0 = 999999984306749439;
    long long a1 = 999999984306749440;    // Hex number: 0x0DE0B6B000000000
    long long a2 = 999999984306749441;
    float     b = 999999984306749440.f;   // This number can be represented exactly by a `float`.

    printf("%lli less_than %20.1f = %i\n", a0, b, long_long_less_than_double(a0, b));  // Implicit conversion from float to double
    printf("%lli less_than %20.1f = %i\n", a1, b, long_long_less_than_double(a1, b));

    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n", a0, b, long_long_equals_double(a0, b));
    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n", a1, b, long_long_equals_double(a1, b));
    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n\n", a2, b, long_long_equals_double(a2, b));


    long long c0 = 1311693406324658687;
    long long c1 = 1311693406324658688;   // Hex number: 0x1234123412341200
    long long c2 = 1311693406324658689; 
    double     d = 1311693406324658688.0; // This number can be represented exactly by a `double`.

    printf("%lli less_than %20.1f = %i\n", c0, d, long_long_less_than_double(c0, d));
    printf("%lli less_than %20.1f = %i\n", c1, d, long_long_less_than_double(c1, d));

    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n", c0, d, long_long_equals_double(c0, d));
    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n", c1, d, long_long_equals_double(c1, d));
    printf("%lli equals    %20.1f = %i\n", c2, d, long_long_equals_double(c2, d));


    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to split the 64 bits integer `i` in 32 upper bits `i_hi` and 32 lower bits `i_lo`, 
which are converted to doubles `x_hi` and `x_lo` without any rounding errors.
If double `y` is close to `x_hi`, then the floating point subtraction `y - x_hi` is exact,
due to [Sterbenz' lemma](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/nathalie.revol/teaching/ValCS06-07/lecture-notes2.pdf).
So, instead of `x_lo + x_hi < y`, we can test for `x_lo < (y - x_hi)`, which is more accurate!
If double `y` is not close to `x_hi` then `y - x_hi` is inacurate, but in that case we 
don't need the accuracy because then `|y - x_hi|` is much larger than `|x_lo|`. In other words:
If `i` and `y` differ much than we don't have to worry about the value of the lower 32 bits.

Output:

```
    999999984306749439 less_than 999999984306749440.0 = 1
    999999984306749440 less_than 999999984306749440.0 = 0
    999999984306749439 equals    999999984306749440.0 = 0
    999999984306749440 equals    999999984306749440.0 = 1
    999999984306749441 equals    999999984306749440.0 = 0

    1311693406324658687 less_than 1311693406324658688.0 = 1
    1311693406324658688 less_than 1311693406324658688.0 = 0
    1311693406324658687 equals    1311693406324658688.0 = 0
    1311693406324658688 equals    1311693406324658688.0 = 1
    1311693406324658689 equals    1311693406324658688.0 = 0
```

Comment: This is clever. It's the simplest algorithm so far, but it [appears](http://quick-bench.com/yCQYVXI_PpqEqc8hiq4N2bpEI2U) to be slightly slower than what @chux has suggested.

Comment: This also work for comparing long long to float: first convert float to double (exact) then compare long long to double... Same for shorter int type.

Comment: @aka.nice. Indeed that is what I meant. Calling `long_long_less_than_double` with a float argument converts the float to double. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nice to see the benchmark! One possible advantage of my solution is that in principle SIMD vectorization, e.g. AVX2 wth [intel intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) is possible, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148578/2439725). (Probably chux' solution is also well vectorizable) This means that you can do 4 compares simultaneously, but this will only be successful if it is possible to vectorize the surrounding code too. Note that in the real world the performance might be slightly worse or better than the micro benchmark suggests.

Comment: I think the code [here](http://quick-bench.com/I3UsfoDhSvoPystUTxc68CyKlZE) produces the same result as your code. This code is still slower than chux' idea, but you can see that it is branchless, and therefore it is suitable for vectorization. This might lead to a significant speedup, if it is possible to vectorize the performance critical surrounding code too, as I wrote before.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it recently in opensmalltalk VM for comparing bounded integers:

1. convert the integer as floating point (values is rounded, thus maybe inexact)
2. compare if both float values are equal
3. if they are not, there is no ambiguity whatever the rounding error, thus perform the comparison of floating point values and return the result
4. if they are equal, then convert the floating point as integer and perform comparison of integer values

The last point may lead to a difficulty: the conversion floating point->integer might lead to an integer overflow. You must thus make sure that you use a larger integer type for that edge cases, or fallback to Bathseba's algorithm.

In OpenSmalltalk VM, that's not a problem because SmallInteger are on 61 bits at most, so I did not attempt to solve it.

I have a Smallissimo blog entry giving additional pointers:

[How to compare exact value of SmallInteger and Float in Smalltalk](https://smallissimo.blogspot.com/2019/09/how-to-compare-exact-value-of.html)

For unbounded (arbitrarily large) integers, the comparison is performed in Integer, but there are a few tricks to accelerate the comparison. This is not done in the VM but in Smalltalk code (Squeak is a good example).

Answer (score -3):

Use double, not float. Take the double value + 0.5. Truncate it by static cast to long long. Now compare the two long longs.

Comment: Fails on edge cases sadly.

Comment: What is the value is too big to be represented by the integer type?

Comment: even double will hardly hold this large numbers with enough precision.

Comment: Just throwing more bits at the problem is not a good solution unless you have actually verified that it'll give you enough for all your possible inputs. There's no evidence of such reasoning here.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Then you know the comparison is false because the other operand couldn't have held the value

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't suggest to vet the input. If the numbers are not guaranteed somehow to be reasonable, then by all means vet the input with use of std::numeric_limits.